# Electric Diople potential derivation

Tags: electrostatics, potential, vectors, dipole

I was looking into the potential created by two point charges at a point $r$ away, as shown in the diagram below and it is given as

$$V(r) = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_o} \left(\frac{1}{|\vec{r} - \vec{d}/2|} - \frac{1}{|\vec{r}+\vec{d}/2|}\right)$$ for $|\vec{d}|\ll |\vec{r}|$ .

I was wondering how the distance for the charges to the point is $|r - d/2|$ and $|r + d/2|$ for this case.

[image]

Comment: It is a vector form: $\vec{r} \pm \vec{d}/2$. Then, it will be written as $\sqrt{r^2 + d^2 \pm 2 r d \cos\theta}.$

Comment: @ytlu Could you please expand on this? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The distance from $+q$ (at $\vec{d}/2$ ) to point $\vec{r}$ is $|\vec{r}- \vec{d}/2|$.

And The distance from $-q$ (at $-\vec{d}/2$) to point $\vec{r}$ is $|\vec{r}+ \vec{d}/2|$.

Thus the potential at $\vec{r}$

$$ V(\vec{r}) = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_o} \left( \frac{1}{|\vec{r} - \frac{\vec{d}}{2}|} - \frac{1}{|\vec{r} + \frac{\vec{d}}{2}|} \right) $$ for $d<<r$

Express in term of angle $\theta$

$$ V(\vec{r}) = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_o} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + \frac{d^2}{4} - rd \cos\theta} } - \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + \frac{d^2}{4} + rd \cos\theta}} \right) $$

Then apply Lengendre expansion in the denominators.

$$
   \frac{1}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r'}|} = \sum_n \frac{r_<^n}{r_>^{n+1}} P_n(\cos\theta)
$$

Then, we have the potential

$$
V(\vec{r}) = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_o}  \sum_n \frac{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^n}{r^{n+1}}  \left( P_n(\cos\theta)
-  P_n(-\cos\theta) \right) \\
\approx \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_o}\frac{d}{r^2}\cos\theta 
$$